# update duplicates data in relationship flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask-restless API to add and retrieve data from a database. 
Some of the fields need to be localised for the clients so there is an auxiliary table with the language and string for each field.

```
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'myclass'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)   
    translated_field = relationship('TranslatedField')
```

And the translation table:

```
class TranslatedField(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'translated_field'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    myclassID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('myclass.id'))
    language = Column(String(2))
    value = Column(Text)
```

Inserts through JSON work fine with {...,"translated_field":[{"language":"en", "value": "some value"}],...}

But when i do the same with a `PUT` request, it sets the myClassID to null in the existing row in the `translated_field` table and inserts a new row with the modified data rather than updating the existing one.

Obviously this is not ok because it fills the database with garbage. 
The question is: Can i get it to just modify the existing rows or do i have to "clean" the DB manually in a pre or post processor?

Comment: What does the query do specifically when you do the PUT request?

Comment: @LeandroPoblet it does what is expected, it updates all the values supplied but when it gets to the translated field, instead of modifying the existing row in the table it sets the myClass foreign key to null and inserts a new row with the updated values and the correct foreign key. From a user's perspective it works fine. problem is that now there is 1 row of useless data in the database. This is what i'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It turns out I wasn't passing any values for the primary key (autoincrement id) of the related objects so it didn't know what to update.

request fragment should look like this `...,"translated_field":[{"id":3 "language":"en", "value": "some value"}],...}`